# How to perform operation on flask-admin database columns to store results in other column of same table

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am building flask admin app where I need to store total of couple of integer columns into third column of same table.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask_admin import Admin

application = Flask(__name__)
project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
database_file = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir,"testing.db"))
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
application.secret_key = "ssshhhh"
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

admin = Admin(application,name="FLASK")

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("ID",db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    first_no = db.Column("First_no",db.Integer)
    second_no = db.Column("Second_no",db.Integer)
    total = db.Column("Total",db.Integer)

class TestView(ModelView):
    page_size = 20
    edit_modal = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    admin.add_view(TestView(Test, db.session))
    application.run(debug=True)
```

Above example let me store values in all three fields manually which is not expected.

Expected result that I am looking for get total of couple of integers and stores in database as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two options you can use:

1. Use the [`onupdate`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions) parameter of `Column` to set the value of `total` on update, for example: 
   `total = db.Column("Total", db.Integer, onupdate=first_no + second_no)`
2. Use a `hybrid_property` to calculated the total without storing the value:

```
class Test(db.Model):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def total(self):
        return self.first_no + self.second_no
```

Comment: Thanks dylanj.nz , I am looking to store value in database , but for some reason after using "onupdate" it is not working as expected . here is below code.

Comment: When i am fetching total value from database , it always returns NONE